# Network connectivity: 2 nodes belonging in different subnets but having the same Class C subnet masks

Tags: networking, subnet

I have a small network consisting of a printer, a PC, and a router. The PC has these network configurations: ip address: 192.168.0.50, subnet mask: 255:255:255:0, gateway: 192.168.0.1. The printer has these network configurations: ip address: 192.168.1.60, subnet mask: 255:255:255:0, gateway: 192.168.0.1. My question is, if I leave the PC and printer's network configuration as is, is there a way for my PC to connect to the printer to print something. Is there a setting I can configure in the router?

Answer (score 1):

Your setup will never work like that. Why is your printer in a different network (this makes no sense)? Do the following to make it work:

```
Change the IP on the printer to an IP in the network of 192.168.0.0/24 
(e.g. 192.168.0.60 - 255.255.255.0 - DG remains the same)
```

As your printer is now in the same network as your computer, you should be able to use it. Considering all the necessary software/drivers are installed.

Comment: Hi @t.thielemans. I know that what you said should work and realize that my set-up doesn't generally make sense. But I would like to know if there is something that can be done in the router without touching the PC and printer's network config and making the connection work.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want a setup like that? What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps other options exist. But there's no way your current setup will work. If you want to use multiple subnets, the only thing I can think of is using VLANs. But I doubt your router will support them. It's also quite a bit of configuration with no benefit.

Comment: @t.thielmans. I'm off to try the "best solution"/best answer to this guy's question. It might work. http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1647778/connect-lan.html

Comment: But why make it that difficult? You'll need to buy an extra router just because you're too stubborn to use 1 subnet :P If you have a second router, of course you can create a second subnet. It's up to you what you do, but you're making unnecessary costs.